# Fill in the Blank Question

Tags: grammar

> We decided to lease the apartment _______ the landlord offered a discount.

1) because 
2) that

people say the answer is 1) because but somehow
2) that sounds also natural.

Can both be correct? or putting 2) that in the sentence won't be grammatical?

What about

> We decided to lease the apartment that the landlord offered a discount on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You propose three sentences:

> We decided to lease the apartment **because** the landlord offered a
>   discount.
>
> We decided to lease the apartment **that** the landlord offered a
>   discount.
>
> We decided to lease the apartment **that** the landlord offered a
>   discount **on**.

The first sentence is good, the second is ungrammatical, the third is clumsy.

An alternative could be:

> We decided to lease the apartment **when** the landlord offered a
>   discount.

Comment: Why is the third one clumsy? I agree that it takes a couple of extra words until it gets to the point, but clumsy? It looks okay to me (not a native speaker though).

Answer (score 0):

Putting in *because* or *that* give two different meanings.

For the *because* case, it means that you were thinking about leasing and the discount offer caused you to make the decision. Only one apartment is involved.

For the *that* case, in the form with *on* added to the end so it is grammatical, it means you were considering more than one apartment, and the discount caused you to decide on that one.